# Align custom search button perfectly to the left of my search input field

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me how to align the search button vertically?

Site: http://www.search.no/ysearch4.html

```
<center><form id="searchform" onsubmit="return search();" name="searchform">
<div>
<input type="text" size="40" id="searchbox" style="height:30px;">
<input type="image" border="0" src="images/mal/searchbut.gif" width="87" height="26"</input>
</div></form></center>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Start by never using `<center>`.

Comment: And then properly closing `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your HTML which I've corrected below- as well as removing the use of [the deprecated `center` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and replacing with [`text-align:center` on the form and using `display:inline-block;`](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html) on the child div to center the content.

Then, to vertically align the inputs, simply add [`vertical-align:middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) per the CSS below.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBYa4/)

([demo with no gaps](http://jsfiddle.net/sBYa4/3/))

HTML

```
<form id="searchform" onsubmit="return search();" name="searchform">
    <div>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="searchbox" style="height:30px;" />
        <input type="image" border="0" src="images/mal/searchbut.gif" width="87" height="26" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
    text-align:center;
}
form div {
    margin:0 auto;
}
input {
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: margin:auto has no effects on inline-block elements ;) copy/paste error ?

Comment: SW4; thank you for taking the time to look into this. It looks pretty good now. http://www.search.no/ysearch4.html

Comment: Hate it when someone posts a question,  another user quits some of his/her time to give an answer and the answer isn't even marked as valid for the OP.